# Visual Studio 11 beta with Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, beta, visual-studio-2012

Yesterday I downloaded the Visual Studio 11 beta which looks pretty cool to me so I tried to create a asp.net MVC4 application and installed the azure SDK. Unfortunately the create azure dependency project option was not available in vs11 beta. Is it possible at all to use azure in combination with the VS11 beta? I can't wait to get my hands on it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible with the latest Azure SDK [1] (November 2011 at the time of this writing).

[1] - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/1b87aeb1-6430-47a4-b0fa-ec06a6c51b20.

Answer (score 1):

The one workaround I would propose is to use the MVC4 Beta for Visual Studio 2010 instead of Visual Studio 11.

MVC 4 Beta for VS2010 is pretty much the same thing as VS 11...the two things that you would miss are the PageInspector for development (which is nice, but I always use browser dev tools to hack stuff on the view quickly) and the syntactic sugar for asynchronous controller actions (async/await).  You can deploy MVC4 Beta to Azure and it includes a go-live license.

Edit:  Here is a link with the "workaround" for a side-by-side installation and using Azure with VS 2010 and VS 11 Beta: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/vs11/

Comment: Alright I'll just use VS2010/MVC4 than with Azure until there is an update for VS 11. I hope they release that soon the VS11 beta looks pretty cool to me.

Comment: It looks like all the things that are beta now are going to be released "around" the Windows 8 timeframe.  So, I would not count on some next month release.  Although ASP.NET MVC4 could come out sooner (out of band).  However, there are some links to it with VS 11 (PageInspector and C# 5 async stuff).  The only release that effects VS 11 that will come out sooner is SQL Server 2012, which is next weeek.